# Is it possible to send image when sending a push notification to iphone/ipad device ?? (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to send image when sending a push notification to iphone/ipad device ? ie. when normally a notification received to iphone it is either of the alertview form or badge form, but i want to also show image with notification message. Is it possible ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, not with the current notification system.